# How to add click event on python folium maps

Tags: python-3.x, maps, folium

I'm using folium maps for my website but I want to make it more interactive. I'm having GeoJson Data of Indian States and Districts and On clicking particular area how to display(highlight) only that area?

[Here is Indian Map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oV3Z2.png)

On Click event how to make it like below.

[Highlighted Map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sa1WN.png)